# Populating Users table with foreign key constraint onto another table in Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I added a column `account_id` with foreign key constraint onto the accounts table to my users table.

For the registration process I now want the `email` to be first inserted into the accounts table. Then I want to populate the users table with the `account_id` and all other registration information.

My **RegisterController.php** looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Account;
use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
//            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
       $account = Account::create([
            'email' => $data['email'],
        ]);


        return User::create([
//            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'account_id' => $accounts['id'],
        ]);
    }
}
```

My **Account.php** looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Account extends Model
{
  public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('User','account_id');
    }
}
```

And my **Users.php** looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function account()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Account');
    }

}
```

This doesn't seem to work though. I'm new to Laravel and am a bit lost here. Any pointers would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add following line at the top

```
use App\Account;
```

You need to define model name at the controller. This is the reason for your error.

**UPDATE**

When you use `namespace` in `RegisterController` like this:

```
namespace App\HTTP\Controllers\Auth;
```

Then your `RegisterController.php` file must be inside `App\HTTP\Controllers\Auth`.

When you create controller using artisan command like this:

```
php artisan make:controller RegisterController
```

Then, In default `RegisterController.php` is created at `App\HTTP\Controllers\`. So, you need to change `namespace` as

```
namespace App\HTTP\Controllers;
```

Then your problem will be solved.

Comment: Thanks. How would I set up my model correctly? I ran `php artisan make:model Account` and then set up Account.php like so: 

`<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Account extends Model
{
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo("App\User");
    }
}`

And now I get this error: `Class App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController does not exist
`

Comment: Just add above line at the controller. what are the other fields of Account table. Did you define the other column fields as nullable ?

Comment: Yes, all other fields are nullable and I added  

`use App\Account;` to the top of my RegisterController file

Comment: The error is not about your model . Can you add your route to `create()` controller function

Comment: Sorry, how exactly do I do that?

Comment: @master_od you have problem with `namespace` used in your controller. That's the reason behind `does not exist` problem.

Comment: Thanks again for your help but I think I'm a bit lost. So the steps I need to take are: 1. using migration, create accounts table, add account_id foreign key to users. 2. create model Account.php containing `<?php namespace App; use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model; class Account extends Model { public function user(){ return $this->belongsTo("App\User"); } }`. 3. Add `use App\Account;` to RegisterController and change create function() as I did in the above. Which step am I missing?

Comment: Can you add code of namespace line used in top of register controller please ? Where is the location of RegisterController.php file ?